# React Navigation headerRight not visible

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am trying to render a button right to the screen header title. But I am not getting the desired result. I have referred react-navigation official [doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/header-buttons/#:%7E:text=The%20most%20common%20way%20to%20interact%20with%20a,but%20also%20a%20normal%20place%20to%20put%20buttons%29.). This is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqK2g.png) for my screen.

This is the code snippet for my navigation.

```
 <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{
                headerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: Colors.header.backgroundColor,
                },
                headerTintColor: Colors.header.fontColor,
                headerTitleAlign: 'left',
                headerTitleStyle: {
                    fontSize: Fonts.size.regular
                }
            }}>
                <Stack.Screen name='Home' component={Home} options={{
                    headerTitle: 'Seguro',
                    headerRight: () => {
                        <Button              // I want to render this button
                            onPress={() => console.log('This is a button!')}
                            title="Info"
                            color="#fff"
                        />
                    }
                }} />
                <Stack.Screen name='Login' component={Login} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Problem is you are not returning anything.

Option 1 : implicit return..enclosing in brackets makes it implicit return

```
<Stack.Screen name='Home' 
     component={Home} 
     options={{
                    headerTitle: 'Seguro',
                    headerRight: () => (
                        <Button             
                            onPress={() => console.log('This is a button!')}
                            title="Info"
                            color="#fff"
                        />
                    )
            }} />
```

Option 2: Explicit return

```
<Stack.Screen name='Home' 
     component={Home} 
     options={{
                    headerTitle: 'Seguro',
                    headerRight: () => { 
                       return (
                        <Button             
                            onPress={() => console.log('This is a button!')}
                            title="Info"
                            color="#fff"
                        />
                    )
              }
            }} />
```

Comment: Damn! You saved my day. How can I miss this thing

Comment: You saved my life. What I was doing wrong is type {} after () =>, remember implicit return..enclosing in brackets makes it implicit return. () => () not () => {}